# Pandas merge with inner join returns KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge two Pandas dataframes using an inner join.

Dataframe A has this structure:

```
Date    datetime64[ns]
KR                  int64
dtype: object
```

Dataframe B has this structure:

```
Date        datetime64[ns]
US                   int64
Location            object
GeoId               object
dtype: object
```

My merge code is as follows:

```
C = pd.merge(A,B[['US']], on=['Date'], how='inner')
```

Jupyter Notebook returns the following error when I run the code:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

I've tried about 10 different ways and all of them return errors. Would appreciate some help to point out what is wrong.

Comment: You are only selecting the 'US' column from B.  You need atleast B[['Date', 'US']] in order to join on 'Date'.  You cannot join on a colum that isn't present in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
C = pd.merge(A, B[['Date', 'US']], on='Date')
```

With B[['US']], there is no 'Date' column in that view of the B dataframe.

Comment: That was it, Scott. Thank you very much for your help!